# Tkinter Listbox highlights one element in blue, but puts black border around another?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tk-toolkit

I'm writing an application with a Tkinter GUI which includes long listboxes that I would like to be keyboard accessible.

Scrolling one item at a time with the arrow keys is tedious, so I'd like to allow users to move through the list more quickly, by typing out the names of elements, and also making <kbd>page up</kbd>, <kbd>page down</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd>, and <kbd>end</kbd> work.

The problem is, when I use `Listbox`'s `select_set()` method, it doesn't seem to do quite the same thing that clicking on an item or moving with the arrow keys does.

When I press an arrow key or click to select an item, it'll both highlight that item in blue and put a black border around it.

When I just use the `select_set()` method, it only moves the blue highlight to the desired item. The black border stays around the item where it was before.

This causes a problem, because then if I subsequently move my selection by pressing the up/down arrow keys, it'll select the item above/below the item which had the black border, not the item which was highlighted in blue.

My question is, how can I move the black border to the correct item in addition to the blue highlight?

Here's a screenshot that shows the blue highlight and black border out of sync:

[image: Image showing the problem]

Here's some minimal code which reproduces the problem. I removed the implementation for <kbd>end</kbd>, <kbd>page up</kbd>, and <kbd>page down</kbd>, but you can still see the problem by selecting any element other than the first one with your mouse, then pressing <kbd>home</kbd>.

```
from Tkinter import END, Listbox, Tk

top = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(top)
listbox.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
for item in ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Last']:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

def onKey(e):
    if e.keysym == 'Home':
        listbox.select_clear(0, END)
        listbox.select_set(0)

listbox.bind('<Key>', onKey)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because the function `Listbox.select_set(index)` just select the item of the index you give, and the blue highlight shows which item you select.
You need to use the function `Listbox.activate(index)` to activate the item of the index you give, and then the black border shows which item you activate.

I have tried your code, and I add one line `listbox.activate(0)` bellow the function `listbox.select_set(0)`.
After adding this line of code, the blue highlight and the black border will move to the first item together when users press <kbd>home</kbd>.

Comment: Was about to post this - you beat me by 2 minutes. :)

Comment: The selection and the activation (which is formally what you're pointing at when using the keyboard to navigate) are entirely separate, and this is necessary to implement some selection modes (notably the `extended` mode). Usually this is left to the low-level controller code in Tk; you hardly ever have to care about this detail in your own code.

Comment: Great, thanks! I actually saw that method in my documentation, but their description of an `activated` element was one that was underlined, not one surrounded by a black box, so I didn't think to try it. They also didn't bother to describe why the `activated` element was important at all. Do you happen to have better documentation than this: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm ?

Comment: One other small thing - I needed to add in the line `listbox.see(0)` below `listbox.activate(0)`. It wasn't necessary in my minimal reproduction where there's only 4 elements, but in my full program there can be any number of elements (one of my test datasources has 400 elements). Without that line, you may select and activate the element, but you can't actually see it.

Comment: @ArtofWarfare Thanks! I didn't notice that problem.